# Nested React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I'm having an issue with my router. Can someone please help me. I have nested router in my pattern-library. When I click on the link, it goes to the homepage even though if I have set the correct path.

Thank You

**Index.js**

```
<Provider store={store} >
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route exact path='/about-me' component={AboutMePage}/>
          <Route exact path='/pattern-library' component={PatternLibrary}/>
          <Redirect to="/" />
```

**PatternLibrary.js**

```
const PatternLibrary = ({ match }) => {return(
<div className='patternLibraryPage Page'>
  <ThemePanel />
  <div className='wrapper'>
    <Header />
    <Navigation />
    <switch>
      <Route path={match.path} exact component={DesignComponent} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/design-component`} exact component={DesignComponent} />
    </switch>
  </div>
</div>);};
```

**Navigation.js**

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  collapse : false,
  navTitle : 'Design Element'
};}                                             
onClickCollapseMenu(e){
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });} 
onClickSetTitle(title){
this.setState({
  navTitle : title
});}                                                            
render () {
return(
  <nav className='nav'>
    <div className='container'>
    <div className='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle collapsed' onClick={this.onClickCollapseMenu.bind(this)}>
        <span className='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i className='fa fa-bars'></i>
      </button>
      <a className='navbar-brand page-scroll' href='#page-top'>{this.state.navTitle}</a>
    </div>

    <div className={classnames('collapse navbar-collapse', { 'in' : this.state.collapse})}>
      <ul className='navbar navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><NavLink to='/pattern-library/design-component' activeClassName="active" className='navbar-link' onClick={this.onClickSetTitle.bind(this, 'Design Elements')}>Design Components</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to='/pattern-library/ui-components' activeClassName="active" className='navbar-link' onClick={this.onClickSetTitle.bind(this, 'Design Elements')}>UI Components</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to='/pattern-library/js-components' activeClassName="active" className='navbar-link' onClick={this.onClickSetTitle.bind(this, 'Design Elements')}>JS Components</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to='/pattern-library/scss-components' activeClassName="active" className='navbar-link' onClick={this.onClickSetTitle.bind(this, 'Design Elements')}>SCSS Components</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have your route set to match the path exactly:

```
<Route exact path='/pattern-library' component={PatternLibrary}/>
```

But you try to route to it with an additional path:

```
<NavLink to='/pattern-library/design-component' >Design Components</NavLink>
```

All you need to do is add a param placeholder to your route config:

```
<Route exact path='/pattern-library/:library' component={PatternLibrary}/>
```

Another issue I see is you need to capitalize the `<Switch>` in PatternLibrary.js

**Edit:**

Okay I forgot about the nested route. In that case you are right, you don't need the placeholder. By removing the `exact` param it should still match and then fall through to your switch in `PatternLibrary`. You're second route is correct:

```
<Route path="pattern-library/design-component" exact component={DesignComponent} />
```

You need to provide the full path, so that's why it's `pattern-library/design-component` and not just `design-component`.

Comment: Hi Chase DeAnda

Thank you for reply and picking up the Switch tag. I have removed the exact match and its working now. However I do have few questions if you can explain will be really appreciable. 

1. Why it's not working when you match the exact path?
2. I have a route with additional path because design-component is the children of pattern-library. Am I doing something wrong here?
3. I'll have more children pages under Design Component, If I use param placeholder Will I still be able to use children pages?

Thank You

Comment: @Mesmerize86 Updated answer. As for question #1, when you use `exact` it will only accept exact matches. So `/pattern-library` and `/pattern-library/design-component` are not the same, so that's why it wasn't matching. When you remove it, `pattern-library/design-component` partially matches `pattern-library/` so that's why it gets picked up without the `exact` prop.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. I think i'll give some more test. I got another issue, my components are not rendering. Is that something to do with that partially matching the route?